# Can't install packages on remote nodes via Ansible

Tags: centos, ansible

I have installed and configured Ansible.  My environment is as below:

- Control Machine is Ubuntu 14.04
- Nodes are Centos 7

Below is my `hosts` file:

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.2.100  ubunansible.intern.local ubunansible 
192.168.2.240  node1.intern.local node1
192.168.2.250  node2.intern.local node2
```

I would like to install packages to nodes but I can't, althouh ansible ping goes successfully from Ubuntu to nodes:

```
# ansible -m ping php 
192.168.2.240 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
192.168.2.250 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

My php.yml as below

```
# cat php.yml
---
- hosts: php
  remote_user: root


  tasks:
  - name: Install required packages
    yum:  update_cache=yes state=latest  name={{ item }}
    with_items:
    - git
    - mcrypt
    - nginx
    - php5-cli
    - php5-curl
    - php5-fpm
    - php5-intl
    - php5-json
    - php5-mcrypt
    - php5-sqlite
    - sqlite3
```

Yaml syntax is correct; it was checked with an online yaml validator.
But when I run

```
$ ansible-playbook php.yml

PLAY [php] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.2.240]
ok: [192.168.2.250]

TASK [Install required packages] **********************************************************************************************
failed: [192.168.2.250] (item=[u'git', u'mcrypt', u'nginx', u'php5-cli', u'php5-curl', u'php5-fpm', u'php5-intl', u'php5-json', u'php5-mcrypt', u'php5-sqlite', u'sqlite3']) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": ["git", "mcrypt", "nginx", "php5-cli", "php5-curl", "php5-fpm", "php5-intl", "php5-json", "php5-mcrypt", "php5-sqlite", "sqlite3"], "msg": "No package matching 'php5-cli' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'php5-cli' found available, installed or updated"]}
failed: [192.168.2.240] (item=[u'git', u'mcrypt', u'nginx', u'php5-cli', u'php5-curl', u'php5-fpm', u'php5-intl', u'php5-json', u'php5-mcrypt', u'php5-sqlite', u'sqlite3']) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": ["git", "mcrypt", "nginx", "php5-cli", "php5-curl", "php5-fpm", "php5-intl", "php5-json", "php5-mcrypt", "php5-sqlite", "sqlite3"], "msg": "No package matching 'php5-cli' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'php5-cli' found available, installed or updated"]}
to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/php.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************
192.168.2.240              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   
192.168.2.250              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem causing the ansible run to fail is given in your final terminal block:

```
No package matching 'php5-cli' found available, installed or updated
```

You should find that this also fails if you try to install it on the node *without* using `ansible`; try

```
node$ sudo apt install php5-cli
```

Remove `php5-cli` from your `php.yml` and try again.

Comment: I did as your says but gave me same error

Comment: Yes Now It is works. I wrote wrong php5 package names after change this It  works

Comment: "Troubleshooting 101" -- a requirement for all would-be users of automation.